# Linkedin share plugin bug on private message

Tags: web, linkedin-api, share

I'm using the following share plugin with linkedin
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin

but there seems to be a bug when i try to share via "send as private message". On the first recipients, the "send" button is disabled. It will only works if i add another recipients 2 or more.. any of you guys facing the same issue as well?

[image]

[image]